# Copy excel file to folder created based on current date in java

Tags: java, rest-assured

The Project need is to copy the excel file from source to destination folder which is created based on the current date. I am able to create the current date & time folder but not able to copy the file there. Getting error message as "Access Denied"

```
public static void writeRequestAndResponse() throws IOException {   


        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

        String currentDateTime = format.format(date);

        String folderPath = "E:\\QA\\Output\\" + currentDateTime ;

        File theDir = new File(folderPath);

        // if the directory does not exist, create it
        if (!theDir.exists()) {
            System.out.println("creating directory: " + theDir.getName());
            boolean result = false;          


            try {

                theDir.mkdirs();
                result = true;
               final String folderpath1 = folderPath + "\\test.api\\" + "\\exceloutput";
                File theDir1 = new File(folderpath1);
                theDir1.mkdirs();
                System.out.println(folderpath1);

                String frompath = "E:\\Project\\src\\main\\java\\com\\qa\\testdata\\APITestData.xlsx";
                //FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(frompath);
                File file1 = new File(frompath);

                //String str1="E:\\QA\\Output\\20200121172737\\tc.api\\exceloutput";

               // File file2 = new File(str1);
              final String topath=folderpath1;

                File file2 = new File(topath);
                //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(topath));
                //FileOutputStream outfs=  new FileOutputStream(topath);
                Files.copy(file1,file2);


            }
            catch (SecurityException se) {
                // handle it
                System.out.println(se.getMessage());
            }
            if (result) {
                System.out.println("Folder created");
            }
        } else if (theDir.exists()) {

            System.out.println("Folder exist");
        }


       }
```

Error message display in Console as "java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\QA\Output\20200122094149\test.api\exceloutput (Access is denied)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out the version of Java you are using. Hence, I used Java 8. Then with these 2 changes, it is working.

1. `Files.copy()` takes `Path` instances in Java 8 instead of `File` instances. So, changed that.
2. In `Files.copy()`, the destination `Path` should point to a file and not folder.

Changed code (with commented code removed):

```
public static void writeRequestAndResponse(){

    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyyMMddHHmmss" );

    String currentDateTime = format.format( date );

    String folderPath = "E:\\QA\\Output\\" + currentDateTime;

    File theDir = new File( folderPath );

    // if the directory does not exist, create it
    if (!theDir.exists()) {
        System.out.println( "creating directory: " + theDir.getName() );
        boolean result = false;

        try {

            theDir.mkdirs();
            result = true;
            final String folderpath1 = folderPath + "\\test.api\\" + "\\exceloutput";
            File theDir1 = new File( folderpath1 );
            theDir1.mkdirs();
            System.out.println( folderpath1 );

            String frompath = "E:\\Project\\src\\main\\java\\com\\qa\\testdata\\APITestData.xlsx";
            File file1 = new File( frompath );

            final String topath = folderpath1 + "\\outputFile.xlsx"; //The output file name included

            File file2 = new File( topath );
            Files.copy( file1.toPath(), file2.toPath() );
        } catch (Exception se) {
            // handle it
            System.out.println( se.getMessage() );
        }
        if (result) {
            System.out.println( "Folder created" );
        }
    } else if (theDir.exists()) {

        System.out.println( "Folder exist" );
    }

}
```

Comment: java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: error message display for the copy -The method copy(File, OutputStream) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (Path, Path)

Comment: Strange. Working perfectly for me. Anyhow, the issue might be related to not adding the destination file name to the destination folder path. Can you try that and tell me?

Comment: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method copy(File, OutputStream) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (Path, Path)

Comment: @Shree Kumar Is it possible to not add the outputFile.xlsx. I want to create outputfile based on the class name xslx. Like class1.xslx , class2.xslx, class3.xslx

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "class". How are values "class1", "class2", etc. going to be determined? If you can get them into a ```String```, surely you can replace "outputFile" with the variable. (Sorry for stating the very evident and basic. :) )

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure excel file exists on same path and the file have access permission. Try to copy the file manually and check that

Comment: Manual copy is working fine, just only checked and also given the full permission to the folder for ALL user manually.

Comment: file location with \\ at the end

so it would be:          String frompath = "E:\\Project\\src\\main\\java\\com\\qa\\testdata\\APITestData.xlsx\\"; . sometime in windows 7 it works like that.

Comment: File should be copied at this location :-E:\QA\Output\20200122094149\test.api\exceloutput  using win 10